# Spring Security: How to validate password length

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Maven, Spring Boot, Spring MVC, AngularJS stack project. For the login page I use Spring Security to handle the username/password form submit validation (from angularJS client). It works fine but I also need to validate that the incoming password field is not longer than a specific length (before even its checked for validation) (I read that this exposes a certain security risk when using ByCrypt, since users can send extremely long passwords, which takes too much time for hashing)

Anyway is there a way to accomplish this with Spring Security? Probably I could do it in my CustomUserDetailService or SpringSecurityConfiguration class but couldn't figure out how.

Comment: Are you authenticating like this `Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        username, password()
                )
        );`

Answer (score 2):

I'm curious where you read the information about bcrypt and the password length? The time the algorithm takes should only depend on the cost factor. The algorithm uses the password to create a stream of 18 words which it repeatedly cycles through. So in fact the usable password size is limited in theory to 72 bytes. Anything beyond that will be ignored.

Here is a quick test (in a Haskell repl, so not representative of binary times) to demonstrate:

```
Data.ByteString> hashPassword 5 p :: IO ByteString
"$2a$05$D2.hLTr0U1xMul/Y2Wsbjeddxp9SNumh5rAe.1oyaZUL4SceCZqUK"
(0.46 secs, 1,673,001,216 bytes)
Data.ByteString> hashPassword 5 tags :: IO ByteString
"$2a$05$bu9zO6ricNsrDTynjLm72emmiIdxulTXFGz0F11WOpSkh/R5viSmC"
(0.43 secs, 1,672,997,088 bytes)
Data.ByteString> Data.ByteString.length p
8
Data.ByteString> Data.ByteString.length tags
1274875
```

`p` is the string "password" and `tags` is my emacs tags file which is 1.2MB in size. As you can see the time taken to hash each is the same. As expected, increasing the cost factor by one doubles the hash time:

```
 Data.ByteString> hashPassword 6 p :: IO ByteString
 "$2a$06$UCIg6bMg57zvl2BM38cAeeg028oQ015Kt4V10J9OpZ3NsInOH.KJW"
 (0.87 secs, 3,311,739,024 bytes)
 Data.ByteString> hashPassword 6 tags :: IO ByteString
 "$2a$06$GpqdSvGMJ/v3H9NycKjBceKE.J9VzrwtYneIFyvlLMyAjUI71AnCe"
 (0.85 secs, 3,311,748,456 bytes)
```

So I think the assumption on which the question is based is false. The size of HTTP requests in general should be limited appropriately for your application but you probably don't have to worry about the length of the passwords specifically.

Comment: thank you, you are right. And how do you suggest to limit the size of HTTP requests in my stack?

Comment: It depends on what your stack consists of. Tomcat connectors have settings for this, so does nginx. It's a pretty standard thing to do with web servers so you will find it if you search.

Answer (score 1):

You can have validation in spring mvc , you have to implements Validator interface
like

```
public class PassValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return yourclass.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
        YourClass myClass = (YourClass) obj;

        if(myClass.getPassword().length() < 8){
            errors.rejectValue("password", "myClass.pass", "The name is too short");
        }

    }

}
```

and in your controller class define

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder){
    binder.addValidators(new PassValidator());
}
```

by having this method you can use validate your input like

```
@RequestMapping(value="/yourUrl", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String foo(@Valid @ModelAttribute YourClass myClass , Errors errors){

        if(!errors.hasErrors()){
            System.out.println("The password validated.");
        }else{
            System.out.println("the password did not validate");
        }

        return "somewhere";
    }
```

also you should add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

to your pom.xml

another approach is Bean Validation you can add annotation to your entities you can read the [documentations](http://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/)

Comment: tnx. This looks more complicated than i thought. Then isn't just adding to my entity class Password field @Size(max = 14) would be enough? But then how can i be sure that its validated before it reaches spring security layer?

Comment: The validation is performed before reaching to Spring security layer since it will validate in your view controller and then it will fetch credential from your DB or LDAP

Comment: I just realized I can not use this approach above, i dont have an endpoint where i can set the validator. Its all handled by spring form login.

Comment: I have not try this but just a suggestion , what if your entity class implements UserDetails interface and in one of Overrided method like

Comment: public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() berfore returning Authority you perform a check

Comment: @ad and I have that method in my UserDetails implementation but its called way later than password is authenticated